# how to install clang in linux for neovim ide

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, neovim

this problem is related to llvm/ clang installationin linux (pop os ) any help will be appreciated
Thanak you !>>!>!>

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/44YGT.png)

I tried to search this problem as many places as I can but only thing I get form those places was frustration .sources (like youtube, several other articles)

and by the way the os is (POP-OS ) Linux

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try reinstalling clang on your system. Some file might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my guess. If this doesnt work Idk what does.

```
sudo apt-get install clang
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're the masochistic kind who loves to compile things rather than use prebuilt binaries, then you're likely to want more than just clang:

usually you want https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/build-essential

```bash
apt install build-essential
```

if you actually specifically want clang:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang&searchon=names

which is

```bash
apt install clang
```

There's also clang-tools, :shrug:

```bash
apt install clang-tools
```